# Handle case insensitive context values

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Adding additional context values worked, following the [Automatic Multi-Site Configuration](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/automatic-context-configuration/) documentation.

But, if f.e. the language in the URL is changed from lowercase to uppercase, it gets confused - you can see this in action on the Spartacus Demo site:

1. Open [the demo site](https://spartacus-demo.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/electronics-spa/en/USD/)
2. Change the `/en/` to `/EN/`
3. You get redirected to `electronics-spa/en/USD/EN/USD` instead of `electronics-spa/en/USD`

Any hints on how to fix this? Or is this a bug that should be mentioned on Github?

Kind regards,
Andreas

Comment: Please report it as a bug in the Spartacus repository

Comment: Will be handled in https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/14346

Answer (score -1):

Please check your configuration. It happens if it has

```
language: ['EN'],
```

It does not happen if it's

```
language: ['en'],
```

Comment: All languages are in lowercase, but the problem is still exists.